# how to parse json String from string variables in Arduino IDE

Tags: json, arduino

I want to parse json string with variables in Arduino. I'm new to code, So facing some difficulties. Here is my code :

```
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#define LED_1 23
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(LED_1, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(LED_1, HIGH);
  while (!Serial) continue;
  StaticJsonBuffer<200> jsonBuffer;

//These are the variable that I want to use in below json[] string
String sensor_id = "gps_1245";
String reg_time = "110520191445";
String sensor_direction = "[48.756080,2.302038]";

// this is the json[] string that I want to use above variables(sensor_id, reg_time, sensor_direction).

char json[] =  "{\"sensor_id\":\"gps_1245\",\"reg_time\":110520191445,\"sensor_direction\":[48.756080,2.302038]}";

JsonObject& root = jsonBuffer.parseObject(json);
  // Test if parsing succeeds.
  if (!root.success()) {
    Serial.println("parseObject() failed");
    return;
  }
  const char* sensor = root["sensor_id"];
  long time = root["reg_time"];
  double latitude = root["sensor_direction"][0];
  double longitude = root["sensor_direction"][1];

  // Print values.
  Serial.println(sensor);
  Serial.println(time);
  Serial.println(latitude, 6);
  Serial.println(longitude, 6);
}
void loop() {
  digitalWrite(LED_1, LOW);
  delay(300);
  digitalWrite(LED_1, HIGH);
  delay(300);
  digitalWrite(LED_1, LOW);
  delay(300);
}
```

This code is Working, But I need to use variables.  So please help me to solve this task. I'm Using Arduino IDE for this code. 
Thank You

Comment: you can concat strings with "+". so something like this? 
char json[] =  "{\"sensor_id\":\" " + sensor_id + "\",\"reg_time\":" + reg_time +",\"sensor_direction\":" + sensor_direction + "}";

Comment: I've tried this but that didn't work, i got this error "initializer fails to determine size of 'json'"

Comment: i'm at work and therefor don't have the arduino IDE in front of me but, try changing "Char json[] =" to "String json =" or allocate memory for it (aka char json[255] or whatever)

Comment: Thanks brother, I turned char json[] to String json.. then it worked. Thank You, you saved my day :)